# JavaScript - Why the strange order of executing codes and then got stuck - XMLHttpRequest - Read URL w/ Login

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

My code is listed below. I added several `console.log` to let me locate my problem. But the return of the code is quite strange, and I didn't manage to find answers here, so I asked a new question.

```
var quote_data = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://SOME.WEBSITE.com/API_QUERIES?&FIELDS=VALUES&output=text"

console.log("HERE0: Begin");

quote_data.open("GET", url, true);

console.log("HERE1: After open");

quote_data.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+btoa('USERNAME'+':'+'PASSWORD'));

console.log("HERE2: After setRequestHeader");

quote_data.send();

console.log("HERE3: After send");

quote_data.onreadystatechange = function (){
  if (quote_data.readyState == 4 && quote_data.status == 200) {
    console.log(quote_data.status);
    console.log('HERE4A: Works Fine');
    var alltext = quote_data.responseText;
    var lines = alltext.split("\n");
    alert(lines);
    }
  else {
     console.log("HERE4B: Error Reason: "+quote_data.status+" "+quote_data.readyState);
   }
}

console.log("HERE5: After statechange");

var split_lines = alltext.split(",");

console.log("HERE6: End");
```

The return of this code is:
[Return from Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5jid.png)

My problem is:
(1) Why after executing the part with `console.log('HERE4A: Works Fine');` the code no longer move on to `console.log("HERE5")`?
(2) Why executing `console.log("HERE5")` first after `console.log("HERE3")` instead of executing `console.log("HERE4")`?

Thank you all for your attention and help!!!

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous.

Comment: Also `alltext` is a local variable in the `onreadystatechange` function. So you can't access it outside the function.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your notice! I am looking over it.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call is asynchronous so HERE5 will be displayed right after this ajax call. You should move the rest of the code into the function like:

```
quote_data.onreadystatechange = function (){
  if (quote_data.readyState == 4 && quote_data.status == 200) {
    console.log(quote_data.status);
    console.log('HERE4A: Works Fine');
    var alltext = quote_data.responseText;
    var lines = alltext.split("\n");
    alert(lines);
    console.log("HERE5: After statechange");

    var split_lines = alltext.split(",");

    console.log("HERE6: End");
    }
  else {
     console.log("HERE4B: Error Reason: "+quote_data.status+" "+quote_data.readyState);
   }
}
```